# occi c++ /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -locci collect2: ld returned 1 exit status compaile time error using makefile

Tags: c++, oracle, makefile, centos6, occi

## Here I have occi c++ application in centos operating system.when I compile my application using make file I got /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -locci collect2: ld returned 1 exit status error.

Employees.cpp file also:-

```
 #include "Employees.h"
    using namespace std;
    using namespace oracle::occi;

    int main (void)
    {
        Employees *pEmployees = new Employees();
        pEmployees->List();
        delete pEmployees;
        cout << "ENTER to continue...";
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }

    Employees::Employees()
    {
        user = "sys";
        passwd = "sis123";
        db = "oel01:1521/OEL11GR1.SAND";
        env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
        try
       {
          con = env->createConnection(user, passwd, db);
       }
       catch (SQLException& ex)
       {
         cout << ex.getMessage();
       }
    }

    Employees::~Employees()
    {
        env->terminateConnection (con);
        Environment::terminateEnvironment (env);
    }

    void Employees::List()
    {
      /*
       * simple test method to select data from
       * the employees table and display the results
       */
        Statement *stmt = NULL;
        ResultSet *rs = NULL;
        string sql = "select employee_id, first_name, last_name " \
                   "from employees order by last_name, first_name";

        try
       {
         stmt = con->createStatement(sql);
       }
       catch (SQLException& ex)
      {
        cout << ex.getMessage();
       }
      if (stmt)
      {
        try
        {
          stmt->setPrefetchRowCount(32);
          rs = stmt->executeQuery();
        }
        catch (SQLException& ex)
        {
          cout << ex.getMessage();
        }
        con->terminateStatement(stmt);
      }
   }
```

======================

here also Employees.h file

```
#include <occi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;
class Employees {
    public:
    Employees();
    virtual ~Employees();
    void List();
    private:
    Environment *env;
    Connection  *con;
    string user;
    string passwd;
    string db;
};
```

My make file is:-

```
Employees: Employees.cpp
    g++ -o Employees Employees.cpp \
    -I$(ORACLE_HOME)//usr/include/oracle/11.1/client \
    -L$(ORACLE_HOME) -lclntsh -locci

debug: Employees.cpp
    g++ -ggdb3 -o Employees Employees.cpp \
    -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client \
    -L$(ORACLE_HOME) -lclntsh -locci
clean:
    rm -f Employees
```

The sqlclient occi library already installed in /usr/include/oracle/11.1/client directory of centos 
The problem is on make file pls help me

Comment: Where is the `libocci.a`/`libocci.so` library?

Comment: /usr/include/oracle/11.1/client in this directery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path to the oracle headers is `$(ORACLE_HOME)//usr/include/oracle/11.1/client` (from the `-I` argument in your makefile) then I find it unlikely that the path to the libraries is `$(ORACLE_HOME)` (from the `-L` argument in your makefile) and it would seem much more likely to me to be `$(ORACLE_HOME)//usr/lib/oracle/11.1/client` (or something like that).

Comment: I make it ,but it is the same?

Comment: @sis Then that may not be the right path. You need to find what the right path is and use that. Given your answer to my comment the path would seem to be `/usr/include/oracle/11.1/client` (though that's slightly odd but maybe that's how oracle does things).

Comment: what is the usual path you know in centos occi library?

Comment: or shall I install again the instant client,if you say yes give me some step of approprate way of installetion in centos Thanks

Comment: @sis I know nothing about Oracle. But this issue isn't oracle specific. You have a library in a non-standard location so you need to tell your compiler/linker about that path. That's what `-L` is for. Get that path right (the path that contains the `libocci.a` or `libocci.so` file) and it should work.